# Download Amazon-RDS (SQL-Server) Backup or Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to download one of my backups and restore it on my laptop for testing a web app locally.  I'm using SQL Express.

This is similar to this [MySQL question](https://serverfault.com/questions/302680/how-to-create-a-local-backup-of-a-remote-amazon-rds-mysql-database). Can I just run a backup using T-SQL? And then somehow direct it to S3?

Comment: One-command-answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/302680/how-to-create-a-local-backup-of-a-remote-amazon-rds-mysql-database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is super easy to do if you follow the steps [Importing and Exporting SQL Server Databases](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Backup)

Key steps being:

- Create S3 bucket
- [Create options group with IAM Role to that bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-support-for-native-backuprestore-to-amazon-s3/), being sure to select the "SQL_SERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE" option.
- Assign options group to the RDS instance

  - Go to RDS dashboard showing your instances.
  - Click your RDS instance to view the details screen.
  - Click the Modify button in the top right.
  - Scroll way down to "Database options" -> "Options group"
  - Select your newly created option group that has the backup & restore option.
  - Save / Continue. It may take several minutes for this change to take effect, even if you select to apply it immediately. I personally did not experience downtime, YMMV.
- Run the backup script:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database 
     @source_db_name='database_name', 
     @s3_arn_to_backup_to='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension',
     @overwrite_S3_backup_file=1;
```

That script will return to you a task #. You can use the following script to track the progress:

```
exec msdb..rds_task_status @task_id= <your task #>
```

Once you've done that then you can download the .bak file and restore locally (assuming same sql server versions running, etc)

Comment: Thanks, I will when I can, and come back and mark answer. 
So the above is to be run in SSMS? Not Windows command line, right? 
They made their own backup stored proc?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: That is not super easy. Super easy would be clicking a download button somewhere.